# how to draw simple eyes in java

Tags: java, swing, 2d

How can I draw simplest eyes in Java's swing ? I would like to get something like that :

http://img710.imageshack.us/img710/70/eyesp.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a filled circle with a outline in a different color, you can use `drawOval` in addition to `fillOval` (don't forget to change the color on the `Graphics` context before drawing the outline).

You should also investigate the [`Grahpics2D`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) class, which has a lot more functionality than the regular `Graphics` object. (You can simply cast a `Graphics` instance as a `Graphics2D`).

In particular, to make the circles look "nice", you may want to set the anti-aliasing rendering hint. You can do this as follows:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

// Turn anti-aliasing on.
g2d.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

// Draw everything you want...

// Turn anti-aliasing off again.
g2d.setRenderingHint(
    RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Graphics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) class methods:

- fillRect
- fillOval

And similar methods to accomplish what you are trying to on a JPanel.

Example:

```
public class Eyes extends JPanel
{
   // override paint
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
       super(g);
       // use fillRect, fillOval and color methods
       // on "g" to draw what you want
   }
}
```

Then, of course, you will place Eyes object inside a JInternalFrame, other JPanel or container as you need.

Comment: +1  Also, "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding paint()." http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html

Comment: @trashgod: thanks. changed the code sample to reflect what you suggested.